# Gluon Mobile Charset Issue

Tags: eclipse, mobile, character-encoding, gluon

I'm getting what looks like Character-encoding problems when I deploy my Gluon App to my Mobile.
On the Desktop its displaying the Text as expected.
Heres a couple of Screenshots (in one Image) to highlight the problem:
[image]

Anyone have an idea what the problem might be?
(Eclipse Project & all Sources encoded with UTF-8)

Comment: What is your Android device? Some brands have issues with Roboto Medium fonts

Comment: Its a OnePlus 3

Comment: Yes, that was the _one_... See some possible fix [here](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/java/com/devoxx/DevoxxApplication.java#L127) with custom [CSS](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/resources/com/devoxx/devoxx_android_sans.css).

Comment: I checked the Display Settings & it is using the Roboto Font.
THe only alternative is OnePlus Slate, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Roboto fonts work in this device, but not Medium, that can be replaced with Condensed Bold.

Comment: The fix references `com.devoxx.util.DevoxxSettings`, which I can't find...

Comment: It is a [list](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientCommon/src/main/java/com/devoxx/util/DevoxxSettings.java#L148) of (one) devices that have the same issue.

Comment: You have to install it (the font is [here](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/resources/com/devoxx/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf). Please spend some time having a look at that project.

Comment: The phone only has `Roboto` & `OnePlus Slate` with neither Condensed nor Medium on offer.

Comment: Did you read my last comment?

Comment: I'm struggling with it. Most of the code was dead simple, but applying `final String voxxedStylesheet` uses a new Class, `com.devoxx.service.Service`, which brings a _massive_ infrastructure with it & as I'm new to gradle its tricky finding a way to import the Devoxx project structure. I hope Gluon are committed to Gluon Mobile as I'm investing an awful lot of time in what could be a fantastic alternative to the rubbish available with Kotlin (and a smidgeon of Java) in Android Studio.

Comment: The solution should be dead simple as well, you don’t need the Devoxx project _at all_. You need only the css solution they applied to the font issue: the CSS file, the fonts files and the small code required to load it, based on devices, for which you will use the Charm Down services. I’ll post this as an answer when I have the time.

Comment: Hi @José, I have had a partial success: with `devoxx_android_sans.css` hard-coded it works. **BUT** the very first line of the conditional coding fails. `Services.get(DeviceService.class);` (in the `postInit(...)` Method) returns an empty `Optional` on both Desktop & Android Device.

Comment: Did you include the `device` plugin? Check `downConfig` in your build file.

Comment: yes, version is '3.8.6' & `device` plugin now added (even though comment explicitly states **NOT** to do so)

Comment: It says to use the Gluon options from the context menu, so you don’t need to edit it manually

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it was the problem. When running on the Desktop, setting `device` using the Context Menu makes no difference.  As far as I can see, there is not a corresponding plugin for the desktop device.  But I just tried an `androidInstall` and the build downloaded the android device plugin.

Comment: Next problem: the Classloader couldn't find the CSS, I had to prefix it with `"/"` and now it works. :-)